# SVN command default arguments

Tags: svn

I am using SVN command line and what I need is to add a default parameter to the command.

Example: I usually use status command with "-q" argument like "svn st -q".
I am wondering if there is a way to apply this argument by default, so even when i type "svn st" then "svn st -q" is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

You cannot alias commands with a space in them, so you will have to write a wrapper script, something like this:

```
function ls() {
  case $* in
    -la* ) shift 1; command ls -la "$@" | more ;;
    * ) command ls "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

See https://superuser.com/questions/105375/bash-spaces-in-alias-name

You can use an alias:

`alias ll='ls -al'`

This will allow you do do what you want for any command, see here for more info:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Comment: Can something like this be done in the windows command prompt?